# Water entry into basement in tricky area

Tags: basement, waterproofing, drainage

I have a tricky water problem. Whenever there is heavy rain, water seeps through cracks in the basement wall underneath the basement window in the picture. The plastic cover seems to help a little but not enough.

[image]

This house is 80 years old. There is no drain tile along this wall. Some of the other walls do have it and there are no other water problems in the basement.

The driveway slopes slightly TOWARD the house.

I would like to get feedback on some of the options I'm considering. Am I missing anything?

1. Excavate down to the footer, waterproof the exterior wall, install drain tile, connect it to existing drain tile, and add a window well drain. This seems to be the ideal long-term solution, but it's $$$$ and I don't know if it can be done in a space this tight. Also maybe not necessary in light of #7.
2. Install some other kind of drain like a french or channel drain close to the surface to catch driveway runoff. The drain tile would have to run under 8 feet of concrete (foreground) to the front yard where the slope steepens, and discharge near the sidewalk, and I don't know if that's legal.
3. Remove the wood chips, install waterproof sheet a few inches down sloping away from the house, put gravel on top. This would divert rainfall over this area, but there would still be a lot of water entering at the driveway edge and getting into the ground.
4. Clean out the crud from the window well and add fresh gravel. One contractor thought this alone might fix the leaking, so I'll try it soon.
5. Install some kind of diverter at the driveway edge to keep driveway water on the driveway. I was thinking some waterproof/weatherproof/UV-proof sheet sandwiched between driveway and a custom long strip of concrete affixed with masonry screws.
6. Jack up the driveway so that it slopes away from the house.
7. Replace the driveway, extending the new one right up against the house, making sure to slope it away. The driveway is pretty beat up anyway, so I'll have to do it sooner or later regardless, and it would seem to make #1 no longer necessary.
8. Burn it all down and start over

Comment: I see the corner of a downspout in the foreground does that go into a drain?

Comment: You indicate that the driveway slopes across its width toward the house. Which way does it slope along its length? Does it slope away from the garage toward the street, is it flat, or does it actually slope back toward the garage?

Comment: @FreeMan It's almost flat, but slopes very slightly toward the street.

Comment: @Jasen There is an extender on that so it discharges about 8 feet onto the front yard, which slopes toward the street.

Comment: I would think that #3, but in concrete would be the way to go, but I'm far from an expert in drainage issue remediation, so just a comment.